# How to get Xcode 4's Documentation window to render based on an external stylesheet?

Tags: xcode4

I used to be able to get Xcode 3's Documentation/Help window to render based on an external stylesheet by setting these:

> defaults write com.apple.Xcode DVDocView.WebKitUserStyleSheetLocationPreferenceKey
>   "~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default/chrome/userContent.css"
>
> defaults write com.apple.Xcode DVDocView.WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey 1

The above doesn't work with Xcode 4 anymore?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the plist file and the keys to use have changed. You should now use:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode WebKitUserStyleSheetLocationPreferenceKey "/path/to/css"
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.  But somehow it doesn't antialias anymore.  I didn't turn off antialias in my css.  Any idea?

Comment: Try changing [`-webkit-font-smoothing`](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing).

Comment: I did this in my css - * { font-family: "Verdana" !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialias !important; }, but the font for the XCode documentation is still not antialiased.  My Chrome browser is using the same css file and its fonts are antialiased.

Comment: Ok, I know why.  Setting this "defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 10" fixes it.